# Using WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc, webmatrix

I have an MVC4 internet project that uses the out of the box WebMatrix security. A requirement has come along to add a WPF front end to the same application. I have moved the model into a separate DLL and started building the WPF front end over the same entities.

The only issue I am having is trying to integrate with the existing security model. I have added a system.web section into my WPF project's app.config as follows:

```
<system.web>
  <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```

Now when I call `WebSecurity.Login("Username", "Password")` I get the following error:

> You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

I have tried calling the `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute();` code that comes with the MVC project in the start-up of my WPF application, but it makes no difference to the above error.

I cannot find any examples on-line of how to do this, am going down a dead end here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to take a different approach and use a WCF authentication service to share between my different clients, as outlined in this post [Walkthrough: Using ASP.NET Application Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515342.aspx).

This was a neater solution than trying to get web matrix to work directly from inside a WPF project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things to get this to work

First in Global.asax.cs add this at the bottom of Application_Start()

```
    var attr = new MixThread.Web.Filters.InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute();
    attr.OnActionExecuting(null);
```

Second, add this to your Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

You should be able to construct a WCF based login like so:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public bool Login(string username, string password)
{
    return WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Login(username, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add this to your service too.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```